# What will Multi-variate Gaussian Distribution become when the quadratic form in the exponent is constant

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I'm reading the chapter 2 of [PRML(**Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning**)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) and I don't understand the following statement in the first paragraph in page 80:

> The Gaussian distribution will be constant on surfaces in $x$-space for which this quadratic form is constant.

My understanding is that the Gaussian will become an uniform distribution when the quadratic form is constant but I'm not sure. And when will the quadratic form be constant?

The quadratic form is:

$$
    \Delta^2=(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)
   $$

And the Multi-variate Gaussian is :

$$
N(x|\mu,\Sigma)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{(D/2)}}\frac{1}{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}\exp\lbrace -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) \rbrace
$$

Comment: Please give references as you would expect to find them in good literature. "PRML" = ??? The fact that many readers here will be able to guess is much less important than the fact that many don't want to have to guess.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for pointing that, I have corrected PRML to Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning

Comment: Thanks but in good literature I expect to see author(s), publication date and publisher. Please don't expect people to Google for basic details; it's your privilege to ask a question, but your responsibility to make it as useful and as intelligible as possible to all who might want to read it.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding what the text is saying. A density (multivariate or
univariate) is a *function* that typically takes on different values for each
value of the argument: $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ are usually different numbers.
For *uniform* distributions, say $U(a,b)$, $f(x)$ has the *same value* $(b-a)^{-1}$
for *all* $x \in (a,b)$ and the *same value* $0$ for all $x \notin (a,b)$.
A (univariate) Gaussian density $f(x)$ has, in general, different values for
different $x$'s with minor exceptions: for each real number $t$,
$f(\mu+t)$ has the same value as $f(\mu-t)$ for the simple reason that
$$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac 12 \left(\frac{(\mu+t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right) 
=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac 12 \left(\frac{(\mu-t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)$$
both quantities being equal to $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$. Writing all of the above gobbledygook can be avoided
by noting that all we are looking for are the points where the *quadratic*
function $(x-\mu)^2$ has the same value, and it is easy to determine that
$x_1 = \mu+t$ and $x_2 = \mu-t$ give rise to the same value $t^2$ for
$(x-\mu)^2$. For a *bivariate* Gaussian distribution, the density
has constant value wherever a *quadratic* in two variables has the same value:
this quadratic corresponds to an *ellipse* with center $(\mu_X,\mu_Y)$ in the plane. More generally, the quadratic in $n \geq 2$ variables is the 
*quadratic form*
$(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$
that you quote, and the set of points where this function has the same value
is a *surface* in $n$-dimensional space.

> The Gaussian distribution never *becomes* a uniform distribution in the
>   usual sense of the word. A Gaussian *density function* **can** have the same
>   numerical value for different values of the argument, but that is not the same
>   as saying that the *Gaussian* random variable (or random vector)
>   is uniformly distributed on those points.

One *could* say that **conditioned**
on $X$ being in the set of points where the quadratic has fixed value,
$X$ is *uniformly distributed in that set*, but this *conditional*
distribution is not Gaussian in any sense of the word.  In the univariate
case, the conditional distribution is a *discrete* distribution: *conditionally*, $X$ takes
on values $\mu+t$ and $\mu-t$ with equal probability, in the bivariate
case, the *conditional* distribution of $(X,Y)$ is uniform on an ellipse
but it *cannot* be described by a *joint* density. While we can write something
like $$f_{X,Y\mid (X,Y)\in A}(x,y\mid A) = \begin{cases}c, & (x,y) \in A,\\0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $A$ is the ellipse in question, that $f$ is *not* a joint density: its
integral over the plane is $0$ instead of $1$, and Gaussianity cannot be
averred in any sense of the word. For example, the conditional
*marginal* distributions
of $X$ and $Y$ are *not* Gaussian distributions.

Comment: Thanks, I Understand a little bit.Do you mean the $\Delta^2$can't be constant for all different points except for the points on the  ellipse in the bivariate Gaussian for example?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Pick any number $z$, say $5.1$. There is a _set_ of _vectors_ $x$ such that $\Delta^2=(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$ has value $5.1$ for all $x$ in the set. In two dimensions, this set of vectors (or points in the plane) is an ellipse. For **all** $(x,y)$ on this ellipse, $\Delta^2$ has value $5.1$. For any point that is _not_ on this ellipse $\Delta^2$ does not have value $5.1$; it has a different value, say $6.2$. This other point that you have chosen is on a _different_ ellipse, the one corresponding to having chosen $z=6.2$ to start with, etc.